# CSS min-height not working in firefox

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox, sass

I'm working on a ReactJS app and I want my body to take up the entire screen at least - using min-height: 100%, with height: auto to account for the screen being more than 100%. This is not working in firefox specifically but is working in other browsers.

Left is chrome, right is firefox. 
[image]

Everything is being held by a div with the body class as such;

```
<div className={styles.body}>
   {this.props.children}
</div>
```

My scss:

```
.body{
display: block;
font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
margin: auto;
height: auto;    
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, #696D7D 22px, #FAF5E3 22px, #FAF5E3 24px, transparent 24px, transparent 67px, #FAF5E3 67px, #FAF5E3 69px, transparent 69px),
    linear-gradient(225deg, #696D7D 22px, #FAF5E3 22px, #FAF5E3 24px, transparent 24px, transparent 67px, #FAF5E3 67px, #FAF5E3 69px, transparent 69px)0 64px;
background-color:#696D7D;
background-size: 64px 128px;
}
```

Comment: Need some HTML to work with. [mcve]

Comment: Your added HTML does not make a complete example of the problem, does it? Isn't it applying body styles to a div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `vh` unit to set your `div` to 100% height of the `viewport`

```
.yourClass {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Hope it's what you was looking for.

Comment: That works - is the % 'unit' not supported cross platform? Or just in this case? Just a strange inconsistency?

Comment: It is. But `height` or `min-height` needs to be `position: absolute`

Comment: @IntoxicatedPenguin see that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maximilianfixl/p53jt5sr/)